# Inverse of an equation with $X_i$ and $X_{i -1}$

Tags: statistics, inverse

I'm trying to figure out the Inverse Transform Method for stats and in my profs. slides there is this:

> F(x) = cumulative dist. function, F(x) = Pr(X<=x)
>
> For the $i$th segment $(i = 1,\dots,N)$,
>   $$F(x) = m_i(x-x_{i-1}) + \frac{i-1}n,$$
>   where $$m_i = \frac{1/n}{x_i – x_{i-1}}.$$
>   Let $A_i$ be the inverse of $M_i$.
>   $$F^{-1}(x) = x_{i-1} + a_i\left(x-\frac{i-1} n\right)
> \quad\text{for $\frac{i-1}n \le x \le \frac i n$.}$$

How do you get the inverse of $\frac{1/n}{X_i – X_{i-1}}$?

Thank you

Comment: Please make sure my formatting did not butcher your meaning. I couldn't really tell for sure what was supposed to be an index and what was supposed to be multiplication.

Comment: Ok sorry about that. That looks correct though thank you.

Comment: It might help to explain more about what $F$ is, what $X$ and $X_i$ are, what $M_i$ are, what you mean by segments, etc. The problem statement as it stands is incomplete.